# Grouping files by common text in names using Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, grouping

I have a directory with list of files in there:

```
ITEM_jazz_list_20160209.txt 
ITEM_jazz_list_20160209.txt
ITEM_piano_list_20160209.txt
```

Is it possible to write one Lambda statement to group the items there by type (jazz or piano) which is part of the text? So i end up with 2 groups of the 3 files above?

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried already?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately, I have no diea how to achieve this

Comment: Have a look at [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx). That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice, as if I didn't look this up for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
var groups = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.txt")
   .Select(path => new { path, fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)})
   .Select(x => new { x.path, x.fileName, tokens = x.fileName.Split('_')})
   .Where(x => x.tokens.Length >= 4)
   .GroupBy(x => x.tokens[1])
   .Select(g => g.ToArray())
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: @codran tokens will contain the pieces between "_" characters.